# attempting a post-deploy callback in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

i use the following command to deploy to various environments/service combos:

```
fab init:env,service deploy
```

init sets the env.hosts depending on what env/service combo is used.

what i'd like to have happen is that at the end of the deployment, i'd like for there to be a single function call (regardless of how many env.hosts entries)

is such a callback possible within fabric?

what i'm trying to do is `git log -1` on each node and compare them at the end of the deployment to ensure that each one was deployed to successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already found a solution but I will answer this as a reference if someone else lands here.

You can do this without a callback using the default fabric execution model, like this:

```py
from fabric import api as fab

def _deploy():
    ##Your original deploy function
    fab.run("something")


@fab.runs_once
@fab.task
def deploy():
    ## The 'deploy' task is run only once
    fab.execute(_deploy) ## The _deploy function is called for every server
    ## Write here the code you wanted in the callback.
```